# Reading Mail Reader Sampler response and asserting content in specific locale

Tags: jmeter

I am reading Gmail inbox using Jmeter Mail Reader Sampler. The email's subject line and body is in Japanese language.

From the email response I have extracted the Subject line and some of the Body content and Now i want to assert those by putting the content in a dummy sampler as placeholder.

**The challenge is the extracted result is appearing like question mark (*Subject: ????????*) in the response of the Dummy Sampler, which every-time fails the response assertion with matching or contains option.** Debug Sampler also shows same question mark.

I have also used the below property in the system properties, but no luck

> sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8

I want to match the Subject line and other email content in Japanese language. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your default locale setting is not suitable for Japanese characters, I would recommend sticking to [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) locale as it's the most powerful one which can work with any characters from any languages, special symbols, emoji, etc.

Try launching JMeter as:

```
jmeter -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

and it should resolve your issue.

If it does and you need to make the change permanent just add the next line to the *system.propeties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

```
file.encoding=UTF-8
```

References:

- [Guide to Character Encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding)
- [Java May Use UTF-8 as its Default Charset](https://dzone.com/articles/java-may-use-utf-8-as-its-default-charset)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

By the way, there is no need to use the Dummy Sampler as it generates an extra SampleResult, you can apply the Response Assertion directly to the Mail Reader Sampler